# Save checkmarks previous dynamic cells as new ones are added to the table

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView with dynamic cells.  These cells are populated from GKSession peerIDs.  The user must select which peers to connect to (multiple peers are required in this case).  As each peer is selected, I add it to an array and then place a checkmark on the cell.  Everything is working fine as long as all peers have been displayed in the table before the user starts selecting them.

However, if a peer is loaded and selected and then another peer is loaded, the checkmark for the first peer gets wiped out.  How can I preserve this?

Here is the UITableView code (it's pretty straightforward):

```
           NSString *cellIdentifier = @"dynamicCellType";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

      //load available servers
      NSString *peerID = [_PeerServer peerIDForConnectedClientAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      //cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:17];
      cell.textLabel.text = [_PeerServer displayNameForPeerID:peerID];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
      cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
```

I'm using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the selection/checkmark process.  Here is the code for that:

```
     if (indexPath.section == 1){
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        NSString *peerID = [_PeerServer peerIDForConnectedClientAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_selectedRemotes removeObject:peerID];
    }else
        if ([self connectedRemoteCount] < _numberOfJudges){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            NSString *peerID = [_PeerServer peerIDForConnectedClientAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [_selectedRemotes addObject:peerID];
        }
}
```

Everything is built in iOS6 but is running on 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple solution....just check my array that stores that peerID's that have already been selected and apply checkmark accordingly.  Was right in front of me!

```
if ([_selectedRemotes containsObject:peerID]){
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         }
```